# Dynamically call methods from a variable

Tags: groovy, thumbor

I'm consuming this SDK on my project: [Pollexor](https://github.com/square/pollexor)

I would like to create a generic/main method to accept any request from other methods.

```
static String thumborGetURL(String alias, String imageUrl) {
    thumborUrlBuilder( alias, imageUrl )
            .crop( 299, 296, 301, 297 )
            .resize( 300, 300 )
            .toUrl()
}

private static ThumborUrlBuilder thumborUrlBuilder(String alias, String imageUrl) {
    Thumbor thumbor = Thumbor.create( 'http://localhost:8000', 'MY-SECURITY-KEY' )
    thumbor.buildImage( imageUrl )
}

static String thumborCrop(String alias, String imageUrl) {
    thumborGetURL( alias, imageUrl )
}
```

How I can make the .crop, .resize, .toUrl and other methods and their parameters from the SDK to be called dynamically from one variable of type `Map` e.g.? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have method's name and it's arguments you can try the following:

```
def method(String a, String b) {
    println "a: $a, b: $b"
}

def args = ['c', 'd']
def name = 'method'

"$name"(*args)
```

If list's arguments length is invalid an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks! Just what Im looking for! :)